# Proper error message is not rendered in jquery validate custom method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This is js code for `jquery.validate`. Just defining a custom action to check an Email ID already exists in DB or not.

If Email exists in DB then render the error message, else no error message on screen.

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailUnique", function (value, element) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/is_email_registered',
                data: "email="+value,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data.message == 'false'){ //means this Email does not exists.
                        $.validator.messages.emailUnique = '';
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("oops I am going in else ! ");

                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors
                    console.log(errors);
                }
            });

        },'Email ID already registered with us.');
```

this is where I am using this method :

```
email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            emailUnique: true,
            maxlength: 50
}
```

Checked the response by logging the data value, but the problem is irrespective of Email ID is registered /not it shows the error message all the time.

What I expect here is, there should not be any error labels if the Custom validation returns `true`.

Comment: since you have a ajax based validation either use the [remote rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) or try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9jt4A/1/

Comment: I too am not understanding why you're not just using the `remote` rule.

Comment: And you don't need to be putting an exclamation point `!` at the end of every sentence!  We don't care how frustrated or excited you are!... we only care about reading an accurate description of the problem!

Comment: @Sparky, can you please share some links which I can refer to check this remote rule ?

Comment: Try the documentation:   http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote